# How can i change in select2 dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2, dropdownlistfor

How can I do in C# to Select item from select 2 drop-down and if item not found then I can write in that drop-down  and save that new search item in the database

Comment: have you tried any code?

Comment: no at this time but looking for the same requirement

Comment: [Try it out](https://c-sharplibrary.blogspot.com/2017/08/create-select-2-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-c.html)

Comment: In the above link, there is only to select a record from the dropdown but if there is no record in dropdown then I want to write in the same dropdown and want to save in DB as well